# What's wrong with my SQL Case Query

Tags: sql

Would like to know what is wrong with my query below?

```
case
b.transaction_id,
when b.total_discount<0 then (ABS(b.total_discount)/(b.total_revenue + ABS(b.total_discount)) else '0' end as pct_discount_off
from transaction b
```

Error message appears.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'
```

Comment: Missing a ')'. ABS(b.total_discount)))

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `closing bracket ')'`:

```
case
b.transaction_id 
when b.total_discount<0 
then (ABS(b.total_discount)/(b.total_revenue + ABS(b.total_discount))) 
else '0' end as pct_discount_off
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this

```
SELECT case 
when b.total_discount < 0 then (ABS(b.total_discount)/(b.total_revenue + ABS(b.total_discount))) 
else '0' end as pct_discount_off
from [transaction] b
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select case b.transaction_id when b.total_discount<0 then (ABS(b.total_discount)/(b.total_revenue + ABS(b.total_discount)) else '0' end as pct_discount_off from transaction b
```